# ruby query interface not working?

Tags: ruby, com, ole

I'm having problems with the **WIN32OLE#ole_query_interface** function.

I use the same source code, as mentioned in the [doc of the function](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/WIN32OLE.html#method-i-ole_query_interface):

```
ie = WIN32OLE.new('InternetExplorer.Application')
ie_web_app = ie.ole_query_interface('{0002DF05-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}')

puts "ie_web_app: = #{ie_web_app.ole_type}"
```

and the output is:

```
# => ie_web_app: = IWebBrowser2
```

but I'd expect the output to be *IWebBrowserApp*. What am I missing?

BTW:  I'm working on a 64bit Win7 and I have now used 2 interpreters to test:

- ruby **2.0.0** p353 (2013-11-22) [x64-mingw32]
- ruby **1.9.3** p484 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]

here's the coclass from the tlb for reference:

```
  uuid(0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046),   helpstring("Internet Explorer Application.") ] coclass InternetExplorer {
    [default] interface IWebBrowser2;
    interface IWebBrowserApp;
    [default, source] dispinterface DWebBrowserEvents2;
    [source] dispinterface DWebBrowserEvents; };
```

and the relevant part of IWebBrowserApp:

```
[
  uuid(0002DF05-0000-0000-C000-000000000046),
  helpstring("Web Browser Application Interface."),
  hidden,
  dual
]
dispinterface IWebBrowserApp {
```

Comment: I don't know Ruby, The first part of the puts and its result are suspect to me. Are you sure it's the same `puts` line?

Comment: @Medinoc thanks - I've corrected this now (I've accidentially copied a wrong line from my tests) - but the output-type is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

The coclass says it implements `IWebBrowser2` as its *default* interface.  I suspect that ruby's `.ole_type` method is using that to generate a printable name.  Can you call `IWebBrowserApp` methods on the resultant interface?  If so, it's an `IWebBrowserApp`, regardless of what gets printed.

Comment: well, since [IWebBrowser2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127.aspx) derives from `IWebBrowserApp`, that won't give me any new information.
Well, maybe the problem is that `IWebBrowserApp` is marked as `hidden` and thus Ruby falls back to the default interface? But my real use-case is much more involved and in that case, the other interface is not hidden or derived - and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Wait, IWebBrowser2 inherits IWebBrowserApp? *(checks)* OK, well, *that*'s the explanation. When an object implements both an interface and its base interface, it often returns the very same pointer for both. It treats them as the same interface, and just casts the pointer when you ask for the base one.

Comment: @MartinTrummer - What's the *real* interface, then?

Comment: well, the real use-case is not fully related to this and thus should be a question on it's own with small understandable example. but since the decision was now made to drop Ruby and use another language with better COM support, I won't invest that work.